# Segmentation fault on copying two struct pointers

Tags: c++, c, struct, websocket, segmentation-fault

The following code is compiled with gcc.

```
typedef struct {
    char *device_id;
    char *device_type;
    char *home_id;
    char *op_code;
    char *arg_name;
    char *arg_value;
} query_state_t; 


enum request_type { INVALID, GET_DEVICE_TEMP};


enum request_type get_request_type(const json_t *root_obj, query_state_t *query_state_out) {
    json_t *query = json_object_get(root_obj,"query");

    if (!query || !json_is_object(query)) {
        return INVALID;
    }

    ...

    const unsigned char *request_type = json_string_value(op_code_str);
    if (strcmp(request_type, "get_DeviceTemp") == 0) {
        json_t *arg_name = json_object_get(op_code, "argName");
        json_t *arg_value = json_object_get(op_code, "argValue");
        if (!arg_name || !json_is_string(arg_name)) {
            return INVALID;
        }
        if (!arg_value || !json_is_string(arg_value)) {
            return INVALID;
        }
        query_state_t *query_state = malloc(sizeof(query_state_t));
        query_state->device_id = (char *)json_string_value(device_id);
        query_state->device_type = (char *)json_string_value(device_type);
        query_state->home_id = (char *)json_string_value(home_id);
        query_state->arg_name = (char *)json_string_value(arg_name);
        query_state->arg_value = (char *)json_string_value(arg_value);
        query_state->op_code = (char *)request_type;

        memcpy(query_state_out, query_state, sizeof(query_state_t)); //Segmentation fault (SIGSEGV)

        return GET_DEVICE_TEMP;
    }
    else {
        return INVALID;
    }
}
```

...

```
int main() {

...
            query_state_t *query_param;
            enum request_type request_type = get_request_type(root, query_param);
}
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I'm trying to memcpy two struct pointers.

get_request_type function takes a json_object and a struct pointer (an out parameter), then returns an enum that shows the result. (INVALID or Request type).

gdb backtrace showed the following

```
#0  0x00007ffff77432a7 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6                                      │~                                                                                                         
#1  0x0000000000401206 in get_request_type (root_obj=0x6263f0, query_state_out=0x7c00000077)              │~                                                                                                         
    at websocketserver.c:412                                                                              │~                                                                                                         
#2  0x00000000004013f2 in callback_web_socket (this=0x603010, wsi=0x625b50, reason=LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE,  │~                                                                                                         
    user=0x0, in=0x6262c2, len=161) at websocketserver.c:473                                              │~                                                                                                         
#3  0x00007ffff79bfd1c in user_callback_handle_rxflow () from /usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so.4.0.0       │~                                                                                                         
#4  0x00007ffff79c39d0 in libwebsocket_rx_sm () from /usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so.4.0.0                │~                                                                                                         
#5  0x00007ffff79c40f9 in libwebsocket_interpret_incoming_packet ()                                       │~                                                                                                         
   from /usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so.4.0.0                                                             │~                                                                                                         
#6  0x00007ffff79bead4 in libwebsocket_read () from /usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so.4.0.0                 │~                                                                                                         
#7  0x00007ffff79c1b20 in libwebsocket_service_fd () from /usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so.4.0.0           │~                                                                                                         
#8  0x00007ffff79c1c0a in libwebsocket_service () from /usr/local/lib/libwebsockets.so.4.0.0              │~                                                                                                         
#9  0x0000000000401586 in main () at websocketserver.c:641
```

clearly, frame 1 is the offending frame. This is what I got:

```
(gdb) frame 1                                                                                             │~                                                                                                         
#1  0x0000000000401206 in get_request_type (root_obj=0x6263f0, query_state_out=0x7c00000077)              │~                                                                                                         
    at websocketserver.c:412                                                                              │~                                                                                                         
412                     memcpy(query_state_out, query_state, sizeof(query_state_t));
```

I don't understand though, I've malloc'd query_state struct variable and I could individually print its members. For some reason, segmentation fault is thrown on memcpy.

Any help would be assisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `memcpy`ing to an uninitialized pointer. Try this in your `main` function:

```
        query_state_t *query_param = malloc(sizeof(query_state_t));
        enum request_type request_type = get_request_type(root, query_param);
```

Comment: That fixed the segmentation fault problem, but now I can't assign any string values into my struct member (I.E: query_state->device_id is always 0x0)

Comment: Offhand I can't see any obvious reason for that. You may want to put breakpoints (or extra `printf`s if you prefer) on each of your `return`s from `get_request_type` to make sure your json library is parsing the way you expect.

Comment: yes, I've made bunch of printf statements to confirm that my JSON libraries are returning values. They are, but it's of const char* type. Does type casting mess up assignment somehow?

Comment: No. The casting is begging for something else to go horribly wrong later on, but it shouldn't be causing this.

Comment: I did memset on the struct and it fixed the issue. Thanks for your help. How should I handle the casting in this case then where I've been given a const char* from the library but I need char* because I may have to modify them?

Comment: By marking these return values const, the json library is warning you that it's not safe to modify them, presumably because of some internal characteristic of the way the json library is storing stuff. I would strongly recommend allocating your own char * strings and using strcpy to get the data into memory you control.